# Having Trouble making a Button group in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is the python script I used in order to make a ButtonGroup in pyqt5
got this Error massage  [image: error]
imported QButtonGroup from Pyqt5 but don't know that's even correct or not.
.

### (GUI with just Two button, more focused on code)

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QButtonGroup
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(399, 405)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = 
        QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40,20,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)   
        self.buttngrp = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()       
        self.buttngrp.setExclusive(True)
        self.buttngrp.addButton(self.pushButton)
        self.buttngrp.addButton(self.pushButton_2)
        self.buttngrp.clicked.connect(self.this_func)
    def this_func(self, buttn):
        print("pressed something !")
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "button 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "button 2"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please mention what's exactly the error you got, with the related lines.

Comment: sorry about that. i just added that..

Comment: You don't seem to import `QButtonGroup`

Comment: You're not importing QButtonGroup, and you're not using `QtWidgets.QButtonGroup`. Besides, you're not even supposed to try to edit pyuic files, as you should learn about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Comment: so i did import QButtongroup ,but it doesn't seems to work @mousetail

Comment: self.buttngrp = QButtonGroup()  rewrite this line to self.buttngrp = QWidgets.QButtongroup() and imported QButtonGroup but it doesn't seems to work @musicamante

Comment: "It doesn't work" is useless to us: what doesn't work? Do you get an error? Do you get any warning? Be clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me. I just worked through all of the errors in your code one by one.

Some of the errors were

- remove QButtonGroup from line one on imports. QButtonGroup is part of QtWidgets, so to import it you'd have to do 'from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QButtonGroup`
- line 13 remove carriage return after `spacerItem =`
- `self.pushButton1` is not consistently named in file in many places you refer to it as `self.pushButton`
- similar problem with `self.pushButton2`. Some places you use `self.pushButton_2`

.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(399, 405)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40,20,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum,
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20,
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum,
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.buttngrp = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.buttngrp.setExclusive(True)
        self.buttngrp.addButton(self.pushButton1)
        self.buttngrp.addButton(self.pushButton2)
        self.buttngrp.buttonClicked.connect(self.this_func)
    def this_func(self, buttn):
        print("pressed something !")
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "button 1"))
        self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "button 2"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```